# How can I "simulate" the behaviour of a C macro in Zig, with an operator passed as a macro argument?

Tags: zig

I want to learn some Zig (that is, literally this is my third day with Zig), so I've decided to write a simple 6502 based 8 bit computer emulator in Zig, based on an existing C project of mine. However I have encountered a problem, I have no idea how I can solve in Zig in an elegant way at least:

```
#define SOME_MACRO(a,b,OP) do { \
   ...
   some_stuff = a OP b; \
   ...
   } while (0)
... much later ...
SOME_MACRO(u1,u2,|); // OR operand version
...
SOME_MACRO(u1,u2,&); // AND operand version
... etc ...
```

Obviously, the real code is much more complicated than this, but the key point, that the actual operator (like `|` or `&`) is passed as "C macro argument".

As far as I know about Zig so far, I can use `inline`'d `comptime` stuff to have similar behaviour as the C macro, but I have no idea how to pass an operator as an argument. This is also a curiosity in me, since, of course, with some meta-programming like pattern (maybe using `for` with `comptime`) I can generate the needed `inline` functions before and I can use one of them on demand later, instead of the same "SOME_MACRO".

Is there some `@builtin` to push directly an operator "name" to the compiler from a constant given by a call parameter or something similar?

Comment: I just want to point out that if you're trying to replicate the exact approach used in C, then maybe you should stay in C? Anyway, you can use `u8` (`do_something('&');`), or maybe rethink the approach? I've used enums in my CHIP-8 emulator (`do_something(.and);`, also I didn't define operations in such a way and didn't rely on `comptime`).

Comment: @sigod Thanks for the comment. Well, I wrote the C code, so I know it quite well, and since I am totally new to Zig, that was my approach to try to port my work to Zig with "minimal changes" as a kind of learning project. Surely it's maybe not the best approach at all, and I would do it differently in Zig after knowing Zig a bit better later than now :)

Comment: If you're totally new, you should probably start small rather than jumping straight into the most advanced topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zig doesn't have a way to pass an operator to a function, instead you'll have to use comptime or runtime branching or pass a callback function

```c
#define SOME_MACRO(a,b,OP) do { \
   ...
   some_stuff = a OP b; \
   ...
   } while (0)
```

With a callback function:

```
fn SOME_MACRO(a: i32, b: i32, comptime OP: fn(a: i32, b: i32) i32) i32 {
    const my_value = OP(a, b);
    // or force inline with @call(.always_inline, OP, .{a, b});
    return my_value;
}

fn OP_ADD(a: i32, b: i32) i32 {
    return a + b;
}

const std = @import("std");
test "my macro" {
    try std.testing.assert(SOME_MACRO(5, 6, OP_ADD) == 11);
}
```

With a comptime switch:

```
const Operator = enum {add, sub, mul, div, bitwise_or, bitwise_and};
fn SOME_MACRO(a: i32, b: i32, comptime OP: Operator) i32 {
    return inline switch(OP) {
        .add => a + b,
        .sub => a - b,
        .mul => a * b,
        .div => @divTrunc(a, b),
        .bitwise_or => a | b,
        .bitwise_and => a & b,
    };
}

const std = @import("std");
test "my macro" {
    try std.testing.assert(SOME_MACRO(5, 6, .add) == 11);
}
```